Name of show where in the middle of a desert a wall/screen to another world is discovered
I recall this show was cancelled by Fox and each episode was its own unique story like The Outer Limits.
The plot consisted of the military setting up operations near this wall, studying and examining it. The wall showed an 'Amish looking' family on a farm. A military specialist discovers that the wall is penetrable at certain times when he see's smoke from a fire cross into the Amish world.
The specialist then sets up an ice machine to shoot periodically against the wall to test when the wall is penetrable, of which he then crosses into the other world when it is penetrable.
He then approaches the Amish family who then consume him with enlarged mouths and sharp teeth. The grand father of this Amish family then does something that makes the wall disappear and creates one in their world that allows them to view the military that is out in the middle of the desert.
The show then ends.

My apologies but thank for the answer!
